# Point density doesn't render

Tags: materials

[image]I am trying to make a shockwave effect in blender, but when I add a cube surrounding the particle system, and set up the material nodes as shown in the image, the particles still don't show.

Here is the .blend file:
[image]

Comment: You need to setup the Point density node correctly and you will need to post pictures of your whole setup or the .blend file for us to see what is wrong.

Comment: I posted an image for you

Comment: I looked at your .blend, and here it renders exactly as I'd expect considering the distribution of the particles. But if you mean that it gets too thick when you say it gives the point, I think you may want to reduce the radius of the point density and/or the number of particles. Increasing the start time of the particle emission and compensate by reducing  the lifetime may also help.

Comment: On my original project, they don't show but on the copy I made does. I only deleted a text(converted to mesh) and removed some music, but i think it's because i moved it forward a bit

Comment: Moved forward? Hm. Quite possibly you tried to render a frame at which the particles had not been calculated. When using simulations, you can't simply skip to a later frame. You need to pass through all intermediate frames, to let Blender calculate what should happen. This can be remedied by baking.

Comment: I got it to work, but I can't see it in rendered view. Why?

Comment: I didn't notice your comment until now. To alert someone, put an @ immediately followed by their name in the comment you wish them to be notified of. Like this @snipers500. As to why you don't see the point density in rendered view, I don't know. It works fine here. The only thing I can think of, is that either you're looking at a frame where there the particle emission has not yet started, or you've skipped over some frames. There may be other reasons, but if there are, they escape me at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you've set the point density to use the defining object's vertices rather than a particle system. Click *Particle System* and select the particle system you want to use.
[image]

Secondly, make sure the emitter itself isn't rendered, by unchecking *Emitter* in the *Render* panel in the particle system.
[image]

Comment: Oops sorry. I was testing something out and I forgot to change the settings back for the screenshot. It still doesn't work though and the emitter is not rendered either

Comment: @snipers500 Could you upload the .blend to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and put the link you get in your question?

Comment: @snipers500 Click the link in my previous comment. On the page that opens, click where is says "Drag a file here ..." and so on. Copy the URL to this question and paste it in the field that says "Enter the URL ..." and so on. Optionally enter a password, if you want to delete or edit the file later. Click Upload. Once done, you'll be given a link that you can copy and paste into your question.